# Passing css module as prop using babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I'm using `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` and need to pass classes via props to React components, as such:

```
import "./style.css"

// Works
<div styleName="a" />

// Does not work
<CustomComponent styleNameOverride="b" />
```

Inside `CustomComponent`, I take the prop and apply it where needed.

When it's not passed to `styleName` directly, the class name is not hashed. Is there a way I can achieve this with this plug-in, i.e. get the hashed class name and pass it as a prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. By passing in the `attributeNames` option when configuring the plugin, I could specify the names of props that I want to be transformed, and what I want them to be transformed to.

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@dr.pogodin/react-css-modules", {
      attributeNames: {
        altStyleName: "altClassName",
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```